# What's no ratchet mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw *Dragons' Den* TV show one of dragons said

*I'm going to <strike>walk</strike> [offer?] you half the money for ten percent no ratchet.*

What's the ***no ratchet*** mean?

[Here is the program link](https://youtu.be/r796K313D0g?t=560)

Comment: I'm not going to listen to the preceding context, but obviously some *earlier* Dragon had made an offer with some kind of "ratchet" condition (an offfer of more money ratchets up the percentage stake in the business that Dragon wants, for example).

Comment: This was the reverse. The Dragon offered the ask for 30% of the business and then additionally offered to give back 10% if the company reaches £60k profit (for a total of 20% company ownership). In this case, it was ratcheting down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ratchet**
To cause to increase or decrease by increments: tried to ratchet up interest in the program.[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ratchet)

As in:

> I'm going to walk you half the money for ten percent no ratchet (no
>   change in interest rate).